# How can I measure the distance between where I'm at the moment and the first circle I have drawn on the map?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have an application where I can draw a route so a simulation start where a boat is following that route. What I want to know is how I could measure the distance between me and the first Circle that I draw in the route(so the start point of the boat)

the circle on the right is my current location and the circle on the left is the first dot that I have drawn.

[image: Locations]

this is how I get my current location

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

and this is how I draw and get the coordinates of the route

```
    // gives the function to be able to draw lines in the map to make a route
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
        line_string: true
    },
    styles: [

        // ACTIVE (being drawn)
        // line stroke
        {
            "id": "gl-draw-line",
            "type": "line",
            "filter": ["all", ["==", "$type", "LineString"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
            "layout": {
                "line-cap": "round",
                "line-join": "round"
            },
            "paint": {
                "line-color": "#3b9ddd",
                "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
                "line-width": 4,
                "line-opacity": 0.7
            }
        },

        {
            "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-halo-active",
            "type": "circle",
            "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
            "paint": {
                "circle-radius": 10,
                "circle-color": "#FFF"
            }
        },
        // vertex points
        {
            "id": "gl-draw-polygon-and-line-vertex-active",
            "type": "circle",
            "filter": ["all", ["==", "meta", "vertex"], ["==", "$type", "Point"], ["!=", "mode", "static"]],
            "paint": {
                "circle-radius": 6,
                "circle-color": "#3b9ddd",
            },
        }
    ]
});
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.FullscreenControl());
map.addControl(geolocate)
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
map.addControl(draw);

// add create, update, or delete actions

map.on('draw.create', updateRoute);
map.on('draw.update', updateRoute);
map.on('draw.delete', removeRoute);

// use the coordinates you just drew to make your directions request
function updateRoute() {
    removeRoute(); // overwrite any existing layers
    var data = draw.getAll();
    var lastFeature = data.features.length - 1;
    coords = data.features[lastFeature].geometry.coordinates;


}
```

So basically I want to measure between the distance between `position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude` and `coords[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the distance between two coordinates using `LngLat.distanceTo()`

Something like:

```js
const start = new Mapbox.LngLat(...coords);
const end = new Mapbox.LngLat(position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude);
const dist = start.distanceTo(end);
```